# use of self keyin Objective C

Tags: ios

I am new in IOS programming.I have learnt in C++ that, 'this pointer' is used and  can be accessed only inside and only for instance function(object method as in IOS ).we can't access ''this pointer'' inside the Class functions(class method in IOS   ).but I have checked that I can also use them(as a self ) inside the class method in IOS. but I don't know ,May be my concept  wrong or not. I have searched many sites. I have checked that,many places it is used..If 'self' can be used inside the class method ,So anyone can please tell me, How it can possible?. Is the concept of 'self' is different as  'this pointer' in C++.please explain it step by step..Thanks in advance

```
#import" ViewController.h" 

@implementation ViewController

+(void)fun

{
  [self action]; //here you can see ,Iam using 'self' for access method  action.                                          

}// but according to C++ this pointer (self)can't be used in class method.

  // not giving any error...please check.


+(void)action
{

NSLog(@" Welcome in IOs world");

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [superviewDidLoad];

ViewController*obj=[[ViewController alloc]init];

   [ViewController fun];

}

@end
```

Comment: You are supposed to call [obj fun] not [viewcontroller fun]

Answer (score 0):

In a class method `self` refers to the class, and in an instance method `self` refers to the instance of the class. So the same terminology can be used but means different things in different scopes.